# how do i set the first page of my site in drupal 6?

Tags: drupal-6

I am new to drupal.

I started ctreaing site but facing problem in

how do set my first page in drupal

eg:

when user type

www.mysite.com

he should redirect to first page....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Drupal admin.
Go to Site config -> Site Information
here you can tell Drupal what page to use as the home page.

You may want to setup a specific node before you do this so that that node is your home page.